# Set RadListView Header Template background to transparent

Tags: telerik, nativescript

fiddling with that for a while, I couldn't get a hang on it. I try to set the header template background of a RadListView to transparent. This works on Android out of the box, but I have a white background on IOS.

Tried all things I could find in the web, which resulted in transparent cells and a transparent pullToRefreshTemplate:

```
/**
 * RadListView (loaded)
 */
public listViewLoaded(args) {
    trace.write('MissionsNearbyPageComponent::listViewLoaded()', trace.categories.Debug);
    if (isIOS) {
        args.object.ios.pullToRefreshView.backgroundColor = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0).ios;
    }
}

/**
 *  RadListView (itemLoading)
 */
public onItemLoading(args: ListViewEventData) {
    if (isIOS) {
        args.ios.backgroundColor = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0).ios;
        args.ios.backgroundView.backgroundColor = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0).ios;
    }
}
```

But this does not applay to the header.

I also checked the native references in nativescript-teleri-ui module (e.g. TKListView.h) to find an accessible header view (like it is there for pullToRefreshView) but without luck.

Does anybody have a hint in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Hey Jeff, sadly not.

Comment: Spent all day trying to find the answer.  Can do the content view but not the Header or Footer